# Symfony validator and dates comparison

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm learning Symfony, and I started a Symfony project (2.8.8 with php 5.6) for a new customer. I have an entity with these fields (php DateTime objects) :

```
/**
 * @var date
 * @ORM\Column(name="startDate", type="date")
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
private $startDate;

/**
 * @var date
 * @ORM\Column(name="endDate", type="date")
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
private $endDate ;
```

I want to validate that start date is earlier than end date. So I wrote a validator in my entity :

```
/**
 * @Assert\IsTrue(message="Start date must be earlier than end date".)
 */
public function isStartDate()
{
    return $this->startDate < $this->endDate ;
}
```

In my controller, I check my form this way :

```
$myEntity = new MyEntity();
$form = $this->createForm(MyEntityType::class, $myEntity );

try {
    // Is form valid ?
    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        // Do things if form is Valid
    }
}
```

But the result is always false, even if startDate is earlier than endDate... I know I can check dates in my controller, but I want to do it with Symfony validators. How can I do ?

Comment: To begin, can you debug your code and paste here what you get in `$this->startDate` and `$this->endDate` when you're validating ?

Comment: @JulienBourdic : They are valid php DateTime objects...

Comment: @PierrickRambaud you're commenting a 3.5 years old question, an answer by Jeet has already been accepted below. Sorry :)

Comment: I gave a even older answer ;-) 
My bad, I removed my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this with Symfony custom callback. Please check the [document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) for the details.

For the scenario given, you should have a validation callback as below :

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload) {
    if ($this->startDate < $this->endDate) {
        $context->buildViolation('Start date must be earlier than end date')
            ->atPath('startDate')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

Note :

- See, the error is set to a field path (`startDate`).
- The code is not tested!.
- Use correct path for `ExecutionContextInterface`

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's working, except that the $payload argument is for Symfony3, not 2.8, and that the comparison operator must be `>` and not `<`.

Comment: Ok, I gave the code snippet from my symfony 3 instance. :)